# Searching basic comments in C++ by regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python program for searching comments in c++ program using regex.
I wrote the following code:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\/\/(.*?))\n|(\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/)')
comments = []
text = ""
while True:
    try:
        x= raw_input()
        text = text + "\n"+ x
    except EOFError:
        break
z = regex.finditer(text)
for match in z:
    print match.group(1)
```

this code should detect comment of type `//I'm comment` and `/*blah blah blah
blah blah*/`
I'm getting following output:

```
// my  program in C++
None
//use cout
```

Which is I'm not expecting. My thought is match.group(1) should capture the first parenthesis of `(\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/)`, but it is not. 
The c++ program I'm testing is:

```
// my  program in C++

#include <iostream>
/** I love c++
    This is awesome **/
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World"; //use cout
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the good order to do that since an inline comment can be include inside a multiline comment. So you need to begin your pattern with the multiline comment. Example:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|//.*
```

Note that you can improve this pattern if you have long multiline comments *(this syntax is an emulation of the atomic group feature that is not supported by the re module)*:

```
/\*(?:(?=([^*]+|\*(?!/))\1)*\*/|//.*
```

But note too that there are other traps like a string that contains `/*...*/` or `//.....`.

So if you want to avoid these cases, for example if you want to make a replacement, you need to capture before strings and to use a backreference in the replacement string, like this:

```
(pattern for strings)|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|//.*
```

replacement: `$1`

Comment: In my cases, these traps are not possible :)

Comment: @Dheerendra: so you only need the simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

use group(0)
the content in 'txt' file is your example:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\/\/(.*?))\n|(\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/)')
comments = []
text = ""
for line in open('txt').readlines():
    text = text + line
z = regex.finditer(text)
for match in z:
    print match.group(0).replace("\n","")
```

I got output as:

```
// my  program in C++
/** I love c++        This is awesome **/
//use cout
```

To help guys understand:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'((\/\/(.*?))\n|(\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/))')
comments = []
text = ""
for line in open('txt').readlines():
    text = text + line
z = regex.finditer(text)
for match in z:
    print match.group(1)
```

would output:

```
// my  program in C++

/** I love c++
    This is awesome **/
//use cout
```

Comment: I don't want the newline character

Comment: for your better understanding, group(1) means The first parenthesized subgroup. In your case is "//" which can't be found for your "/* ... */" case

Comment: you can trim "\n" before print

Comment: Now this is unwanted. I don't want new line after //... but I want newline in multiline comments

Comment: in that case you should use: regex = re.compile(r'((\/\/(.*?))\n|(\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/))') and still use group(1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to parse quotes and non-comments at the same time because
partial comment syntax can be embedded within them.

Here is an old Perl regex that does this. Of interest on a match is Capture group 1
contains a comment. So do while loop using a global search. Check for group 1 matching.

```
    # (/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^/"'\\]*)


    (                                # (1 start), Comments 
         /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
         [^*]* \*+
         (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
         /                                # End /* .. */ comment
      |  
         //                               # Start // comment
         (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?           # Possible line-continuation
         \n                               # End // comment
    )                                # (1 end)
 |  
    (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
         "
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
         "
      |  '
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
         ' 
      |  [\S\s]                           # Any other char
         [^/"'\\]*                        # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                          # or line continuation (escape + newline)
    )                                # (2 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer.

*(Note - the problem you are having does not relate to the alternation order

of the comment sub-expressions.)*

Yours is the simplified regex version to get C++ comments
and if you don't want the complete version, we can take a look at
why you're having a problem.

First of all your regex is *almost* correct. There is one problem
with the sub-expression for `/* ... */` comments. The content must be made
*non-greedy*.

Other than that it works like it should.
But you should look at the capture groups a little closer.
In your code you only print group 1 on each match, which is the `// ...`
comment. You could either check for a match in group 1 and 3 or,
just print out group 0 (the entire match).

Additionally, you don't need the lazy quantifier `?` in group 2, and
the newline `\n` below it should *NOT* be there.
And, consider making all the capture groups non-capturing `(?: .. )`.

So, remove the `?` quantifier and `\n` in the `// ...` sub-expression.
And add the `?` quantifier in the `/* ... */` sub-expression.

Here is your original regex Formatted -
(using *[RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com)* with auto comments)

```
    # raw regex:   (//(.*?))\n|(/\*(.|\n)*\*/)

    (                    # (1 start)
         //
         ( .*? )              # (2)
    )                    # (1 end)
    \n 
 |  
    (                    # (3 start)
         /\*
         ( . | \n )*          # (4)
         \*/
    )                    # (3 end)
```

Here it is without the capture groups and the 2 minor quantifier changes.

```
    # raw regex:   //(?:.*)|/\*(?:.|\n)*?\*/

    //
    (?: .* )
 |  
    /\*
    (?: . | \n )*?
    \*/
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 21 ) 
// my  program in C++  

---------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 43 , len 38 ) 
/** I love c++
    This is awesome **/  

---------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 143 , len 10 ) 
//use cout
```